# Magento 2 Install and Setup issue

Tags: php, linux, magento2, centos7

I am trying to install Magento 2.4.5 on Centos server through Terminal,
But I stuck with setup and installation - https://prnt.sc/_usdY93pCVUW.
I am getting below message when I run `php bin/magento setup:install`

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...
[Progress: 1 / 1323]
Required extensions check...
```

This is the command

```
php bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://xxxxx.com \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=xxxx \
--db-user=xxx \
--db-password=hc?]SsNreqvi \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch \
--elasticsearch-host=localhost \
--elasticsearch-port=9200 \
--elasticsearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
--elasticsearch-timeout=15
```

Comment: Can you please insert the image directly instead of putting it through a link?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to memory limit.
I added `ini_set("memory_limit","-1");` in the `bin/magento` file after <?php tag.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and resolved by **Configure php settings** . You can follow these steps :

1. `php -i | grep "Configuration File"`
2. `sudo nano <path_of_php.ini_file>`
3. Update these values

   ```
    max_execution_time=18000       
    max_input_time=1800       
    memory_limit=4G
   ```
4. restart apache2